# a definition of the phrase " On both accounts"

Tags: meaning, american-english

> hi
>   I have a problem with this phrase " on both accounts". what's the definition? I see this phrase in TOEFL IBT tes 7. the student said two characteristic of something and the teacher said that.

****sorry I listen again to thas lecture and I think she said on both counts and this means in both ways. according to longman dictionary:  on all/several/both etc counts=in every way, in several ways etc

Comment: You need to give a complete context for this to be answerable, but very likely the normal usage would be *on both **counts***.

Comment: STUDENT : finding foods and not becoming a food for other animals. Teacher : Right, on both accounts

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's any possibility that *right on both **accounts*** could ever be uttered by a native speaker who also knew *right on both **counts*** and considered that to have a different meaning.

I'm inclined to interpret this NGram as evidence of an increasing number in recent decades (but still a tiny minority) who've misheard or misremembered the normal usage...

[image]

...but I *do* acknowledge that there's a strong historical/etymological connection between *count* and *account* here. OED's closest definition is...

> **count** noun,
>    5b: *the act or way of estimating or regarding; estimate, regard, notice, note; = **account** n. IV.;
>
>    esp. in phr. to take, make, set (no) count of (upon, by) . arch.*

But I'd *set more [count](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22set%20greater%20count%20by%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22set%20more%20count%20by%22&tbm=bks)/[account](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22set%20greater%20count%20by%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22set%20more%20account%20by%22&tbm=bks) by* this Merriam-Webster definition...

> **count** noun,
>    3a: *allegation, charge; specifically :  one separately stating the cause of action or prosecution in a legal declaration or indictment (e.g. - "guilty on all counts")
>
>    3b:  **a specific point under consideration : issue***

(For the specific *usage* under consideration here, that last highlighted definition applies! :)

Comment: I've heard both. I suspect you're right that "both accounts" is a back-formation combining/confusing "on account of" and "on both counts". But I think the meaning's clear even if the usage is questionable.

Comment: @keshlam: Well, [*You're right on both accounts*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22so+You%27re+right+on+both+accounts+to+hold+your+tongue+A%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) occurs in Byron's *Don Juan* from a couple of centuries ago, which is why I acknowledged some historical justification after presenting the usage chart. But yeah - I still think most recent instances owe more to faulty acquisition/reproduction than linguistic die-hards trying to revive an antiquated form.